# Injective function on the domain of natural numbers

Tags: functions

Find all injective functions $f:N \rightarrow N$ such that

$$f(f(m)+f(n))=f(f(m))+f(n)$$

Where $m,n$ are natural numbers.

Comment: What was your attempt at this? Is there a particular aspect you get stuck on?

Comment: Hint: an easier way to say it is that $f(x+y)=f(x)+y$ if $x,y$ are in the range of $f$.

Answer (score 0):

An example of an injective function that satisfies this property is $f(x)=x+a$ where $x,a \in \mathbb{N}$ and $a$ constant. If you look at the number line this basically shifts every natural number to the right by $a$. This is obviously injective and a function from $\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$. 
$$f(f(m)+f(n))=f(m+a+n+a)=f(m+2a + n)=m+2a + n + a = f(m+a) + f(n) = f(f(m))+f(n)$$
Another thing to look at for yourself is checking if $f(x)=a \cdot x$ satisfies this equation, because this function is injective on $\mathbb{N}$.